# Docker published ports are not accessible except for 3000

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a feeling the question I'm about to ask is silly but I can't find the solution to my issue and I've been on this problem for a while now.

I am trying to run a docker container for a node application with a command that looks similar to the following:

```
$ docker run --rm -d -p 3000:3000 <username>/<project>
```

The above command is working fine. However, when I attempt to map my ports to something different like so:

```
$ docker run --rm -d -p 3000:8080 <username>/<project>
```

...The program doesn't work anymore

EDIT: To answer the questions in the comments. I've also tried ports 5000 and 7000 and I'm sure their not in use.

Comment: Have you try other ports than 8080 ? Maybe this one is already used by another program ?

Comment: docker run --rm -d -p 8080:8080 <username>/<project>. In browser chekck http://localhost:8080 if already 8080 port u can list with ps -af command

Comment: Exec this command lsof -i :8080 return which one using 8080 port

Comment: Try `-p 8080:3000`. The first port is for the host and the second for the container. So if you change the container one, your application won't be accessible anymore

Comment: 8080 there are something running `inside container` with this port ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're attempting to change the wrong port in the mapping:

```sh
docker run --publish=${HOST_PORT}:${CONTAINER_PORT} <username>/<project>
```

Maps the host's `${HOST_PORT}` to the container's `${CONTAINER_PORT}`.

Unless you change the container image's configuration, you're more likely to be choosing a host port.

What happens if you:

```sh
docker run --rm -d -p 8080:3000 <username>/<project>
```

And the try (from the host), e.g. `curl localhost:8080`?